# Match multiple rows one table with multiple columns of another table mysql

Tags: mysql, zoho

I have 2 tables

**First Table**: Contact Columns:

```
Customer ID,Project ID1,Project ID2,Project ID3
```

so one contact will have one row.

**Second Table:** Timesheet Columns

```
Project ID, Name, Owner, Hours
```

One contact can have multiple entries.

I want to match project id from time sheet table to 3 columns of contact table.

I am using following query.

```
SELECT "Customer ID","Project ID","Project Name","Owner",
        "Hours","Approval Status","Status","Project Manager",
        "Sales Person","Account Manager","Discount %","Hourly Rate",
        "Monthly Budget","Total Budget" 
FROM  "Timesheets" 
    LEFT JOIN "Contacts (Boost Media Group)" 
        ON "Timesheets"."Project ID" = "Contacts (Boost Media Group)"."Zoho Projects ID 1";
```

But it is not returning desired result because I could not check it with Project ID2,Project ID3 of contact table.

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Comment: Double quotes around column names? Are you sure??

Comment: Do you **really** have table names like `Contacts (Boost Media Group)`

Comment: And column names like `"Zoho Projects ID 1"`

Comment: please remove double qoutes

Comment: problem is how to match row of timesheet table with multiple columns of Contacts table. Currently I am able to match with one column of contact table. I will remove quotes as well.

Comment: @Gurpreet You need to do multiple joins, one fore each ProjectID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong. I guess you want them when any of the condition (Zoho Projects ID 3 or Zoho Projects ID 2 or Zoho Projects ID 1) maches with "Timesheets"."Project ID"

```
SELECT "Customer ID","Project ID","Project Name","Owner",
        "Hours","Approval Status","Status","Project Manager",
        "Sales Person","Account Manager","Discount %","Hourly Rate",
        "Monthly Budget","Total Budget" 
FROM  "Timesheets" 
    LEFT JOIN "Contacts (Boost Media Group)" 
        ON "Timesheets"."Project ID" = "Contacts (Boost Media Group)"."Zoho Projects ID 1"
or "Timesheets"."Project ID" = "Contacts (Boost Media Group)"."Zoho Projects ID 2"
or "Timesheets"."Project ID" = "Contacts (Boost Media Group)"."Zoho Projects ID 3"
```

Comment: @Gurpreet next time when you need help with the product you are using kindly don't hesitate to contact the support team.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
SELECT `(Boost Media Group)`.`Customer ID`,`tyshet`.`Project ID`,`tyshet`.`Project Name`,`tyshet`.`Owner`,
        `tyshet`.`Hours`,`tyshet`.`Approval Status`,`tyshet`.`Status`,`tyshet`.`Project Manager`,
        `tyshet`.`Sales Person`,`tyshet`.`Account Manager`,`tyshet`.`Discount %`,`tyshet`.`Hourly Rate`,
        `tyshet`.`Monthly Budget`,`tyshet`.`Total Budget`
FROM  Timesheets as `tyshet`
    LEFT JOIN Contacts as `(Boost Media Group)`
        ON `tyshet`.`Project ID` = `(Boost Media Group)`.`Zoho Projects ID 1`;
```